# How to connect grid items by drawing lines?

Tags: android, grid

I have loaded grid items in grid view programmatically .i want to connect these items vertically or horizontally using lines. How to draw line and connect two table items in grid view?

Could any body know the answers?
(or) give me the reference for this?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the grid views in such a way that they contain the image(or whatever you wanna display) and the vertical/horizontal line. 
 Then make the "space" between the grid views to be "zero" and they will seem to be connected.

Comment: Thanks for reply.sorry i am not able to upload pictures to explain my requirement more in details. i can give some examples. 1. unlock android phone pattern by connecting(drawing lines) 9 cells. 2. Cross word puzzle. The same way i want to draw lines to show two grid items are connected. (or) is there any other way to show users that two grid items are connected?

Comment: i want to draw line to connect 2 cells in grid view in android.

Comment: ok, so for this I would say that don't go for grid view.
Reason being, in your case I guess there is no list of elements that a grid view should be selected.
If you have very defined no of views than I would say go for a manual drawing of views because in that case it would be easier for you to draw extra things like line to join the two views.
I will try to pull a sample code for you in the meanwhile.